# SpringBoot ActiveMQ Disable JMX Connection via 1099

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, jmx

In my application I have integrate Activemq in SpringBoot which allow to create jmx connect via port 1099. I would like to restrict remote jmx connection directly. Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code works for me. I be able to disable JMX connection by set system property:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.createConnector", "false");
```